# JSP - How to first forward to a view, and then continue processing method in background?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I would like to first forward to the view "/WEB-INF/views/searchResult.jsp" and then process Calculator.lookUp(Type, Place) in the background.

Currently Calculator.lookUp(Type, Place) is processed first, and only once this method is finished is the user forwarded to "/WEB-INF/views/searchResult.jsp". 
Thanks for the help!

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/search.do")
public class SrchServlet extends HttpServlet{

      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
                HttpServletResponse response) 
          throws ServletException, IOException {

          String Type = request.getParameter("Type");
          String Place = request.getParameter("Place");


          request.setAttribute("Type", Type);
          request.setAttribute("Place", Place);

          //I want the forward to searchResult.jsp to occur
          request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/searchResult.jsp").forward(
                  request, response);

          //and then in backend for the below method to run
          Calculator.lookUp(Type, Place);

          }   
}
```

Comment: You can achieve your desired result via Asynchronous request. Please read [Understanding Synchronous vs Asynchronous](https://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-synchronous-vs-asynchronous)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, but I have no clue how I'd setup an Asynchronous request for the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks if you do not like async requests. First, a forward is definitive: you give the hand to the other servlet and next instruction (if any) will never be executed. You need to *include* the JSP if you want to proceed in sequence. And a trick allows to cause the response to be sent to the client immediately while allowing processing in the servlet: just close the response output writer or stream.

Your code could simply become:

```
      //I want the include searchResult.jsp
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/searchResult.jsp").include(
              request, response);

      // cause the response to be sent to the client
      try {
          response.getOutputStream().close(); // if the OutputStream was used
      }
      catch(IllegalStateException e) {
          response.getWriter().close();       // if the Writer was used
      }

      //and then in backend for the below method to run
      Calculator.lookUp(Type, Place);

      }
```

I could never find whether this was explicitely allowed per servlet specification, by I can confirm that Tomcat supports it.

No need for any `@Asinc`...

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code to make your method async but the Type and Place (just in point variable names should start with small letters) both variable should be final:

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
        Calculator.lookUp(Type, Place);// here Place and Type both variable should be final
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle error which cannot be thrown back
        }
    }
    };
    new Thread(task, "ServiceThread").start();
```

Answer (score 0):

As of I know the below is the better way to solve your problem.

- Declare the logic which you need to execute as part of background process in an asynchronous method by declaring the method as,

> @Asynchronous / @Async

Remember, Asynchronous method will not return anything that mean return type is void. If you need to return some values, you can return Future. Read more about [Asynchronous](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html) process.